# Jenkins Deleting bin\ssh.exe

Tags: git, jenkins, ssh, build, clone

I have an issue when trigger Jenkins builds that it would delete my C:\Program Files\git\usr\bin directory, which also held the ssh.exe use to clone repos via ssh.

How can I solve this?

Comment: I'm happy that you solved your problem. But maybe you should [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to understand better how this site works.

Comment: Thanks, I guess. I searched everywhere can could not find a resolution so figured I would post here in case someone runs into this issue.

Comment: [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Got it...thanks @Kenster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to work around this by setting the jenkins user on that node to only read + execute on the bin folder.

EDIT: Unfortunately this fix did not hold up and failed after a few weeks.